# Linear Algebra, matrix representation

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

Let $V$ be a vector space of all real differentiable functions $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with basis $(e^{3t}, te^{3t},t^2e^{3t})$. Let $D: V \rightarrow V$ be the derivation operator on $V$ defined by $D(f): df(t)/dt$. Find the matrix representation of $D$ with respect to the given basis $(e^{3t}, te^{3t}, t^2 e^{3t})$ of $V$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Differentiate the vectors of the basis 
$$(e^{3t})'=3e^{3t}$$
$$(te^{3t})'=e^{3t}+3te^{3t}$$
$$(t^2e^{3t})'=2te^{3t}+6t^2e^{3t}$$
so
$$[D]_V=\begin{pmatrix}3&1&0\\0&3&2\\0&0&6\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Why do we differantiat the vector of basis? Can you explain it please? Or is there any solution different from this one?

Comment: This is the definition of the matrix of linear operator: on every column of this matrix we put the *action* of the operator on the vectors of the basis.